# Control of string rendered when an object is printed?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, class

In some classes, doing `str(class)` will give you a string, such as `'something'`. However, whenever I make a class, it only ever gives `<__main__.Test object at 0x0000026FB34D70B8>`.

How do I make it return a string, such as `'0'`, or even `'100'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: by overloading the class' `__str__` and/or `__repr__` methods, depending on what you need.

```
class Frobber:
    ...
    def __str__ ( self ):
        return "<Frobber {}>".format(self.someVariable)
```